# Cannot import Gmail contacts into Windows 8 People app

Tags: windows-8, sync, gmail, contacts, google-contacts

I know there is a lot of talk of this around the net, and I have done my research, but I'm still not getting any joy.

In the People app, I have connected it with my GMail account. This is confirmed by the Google icon in the top right where it says what accounts you're connected to.

But my contacts just won't appear.

In Mail, my GMail e-mails appear fine. It's only my contacts that won't appear.

I have been into my Live.com account and confirmed that the accounts really are linked, and have been into GMail and confirmed that, yes, I really do have a contacts list.

Any ideas!?

Comment: There is a comprehensive Microsoft Help page here about how to link your various Apps in Windows 8 to your Google accounts: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/use-google-windows-8-rt Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/zPVS21XFEKk

Comment: I did do my research, as I said, and found this page. I followed the steps mentioned, and no joy. (PS the OP name and my name in this comment differ as I submitted the question from a guest account when I couldn't log in.)

Comment: @CodeBlend: yeah, and the instructions on that page don’t work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Windows 8 will no longer sync GMail contacts and calendars (possibly unless you have a paid GMail account):

http://www.zdnet.com/article/gmail-loses-google-sync-how-windows-8-rt-office-are-affected/